# dashboard not appears after custom login

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I try to make code from scratch for custom login and registration for Wordpress. However after successful login I am not able to see dashboard as admin.

This is my code to check username and password and redirect to home page after login:

```
$username= $_POST["username"];
$password= $_POST["password"];

$user = get_user_by( 'login', $username );
if ( $user && wp_check_password( $password, $user->data->user_pass, $user->ID) ) {
    $user_data = get_userdata ($user->ID);

    if ($user_data !== false) {

        wp_cache_delete ($user_data->ID, 'users');
        wp_cache_delete ($user_data->user_login, 'userlogins');
        do_action ('user_register', $user_id);

        wp_clear_auth_cookie();
        wp_set_auth_cookie ($user_data->ID, true);
        do_action ('wp_login', $user_data->user_login, $user_data);
        wp_redirect (home_url());

        exit();
    }
}
```

This is the extract of what I can do so far safely. I am not able to experiment more on that. I need some suggestion that do I need to code for any role based functionality?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Why are you writing custom code to login, involving cookies? There i function to make login, check [wp_signon()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon)

Here is the code:

```
    $creds = array();
    $creds['user_login'] = isset($_POST["username"]) ? $_POST["rf_username"] : false;
    $creds['user_password'] = isset($_POST["password"]) ? $_POST["rf_password"] : false;
    $creds['remember'] = isset($_POST['cook']) ? $_POST['cook'] : false;

    if($creds['user_login'] != false || $creds['user_password'] != false){
        $autologin_user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
        if ( !is_wp_error($autologin_user) ) {
            //Login Success do redirect or whatever
        } else {
            echo "Username or password Incorrect";
        }
    }else{
        echo "Username or password Missing";
    }
```

Good Luck

Comment: Does it show any message in your `site.com/wp-admin/` ??